# Why don't we use hadoop Writable datatypes in spark?

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop, serialization, kryo

In hadoop we don't use java serialization as it is bulky and slow. So hadoop provide Writable that is quick in comparison with java serialization.

In spark we use java serialization by default and if we don't want to use java serialization that we can use Kryo serialization. My question is, **Why can't (don't) we use hadoop Writable serialization in spark?** As we know that it is compact and fast.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Input and output formats (which are typed by Writables) via the newAPIHadoop reader/writer methods of SparkContext

https://spark.apache.org/docs/current/api/java/org/apache/spark/SparkContext.html#newAPIHadoopRDD(org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.Class)

Comment: but why spark doesn't use these internally and instead of these it goes with Java serialization?

Comment: How do you know it doesn't use these? Also, Kyro serialization should be used wherever possible